# Do I need to set an upper threshold when passing an table-valued parameter from C# to SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

Do I need to set an upper threshold when passing an table-valued parameter from C# to SQL Server? I have an ADO.NET routine which passes a table-valued parameter to a sproc in SS.

This works fine when I pass a `DataTable` with 2 rows as a test but no rows are inserted when I pass a `DataTable` with 180k rows.

Do I need to set an upper threshold either in code or in SS when passing a `DataTable` to a TVP with this many rows? Or are table-valued parameters not designed for passing this many rows from ADO.NET?

Comment: How do you know that you aren't just not waiting long enough for the sproc to execute with 180k rows?   Did you try monitoring with profiler?

Comment: I can use entity framework to insert the rows within a few hours at most.  my ado.net tvp implementation sent all data at once to the db and the expected rows were not in the db when I came in the next morning

Comment: Sounds more appropriate for SQL Bulk Copy.

Comment: maybe the TVP is that slow.   Try it again with a profiler trace and see if the query is started and not finished when you come in the next morning.   Check open SPIDs and see if something is hung.

Comment: I'd be interested in the query and your schema. We regularly insert several million rows via TVP  in a few minutes, if that. (not straight inserts, either). 180k rows in a few hours sounds crazy